# Shared library Error : Symbol not found: __ZN4llvm23EnableABIBreakingChecksE

Tags: llvm

I want to generate a shared library by using cmake `add_library` .

Desktop information:

Mac mini

OS:macOS 11.0.1

Chip:M1(arm64)

LLVM:8.0.1

the console details:

```
  Referenced from: /Volumes/app/factory/nullpointer/build/lib/libtravelchecker.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Volumes/app/factory/nullpointer/build/lib/libtravelchecker.dylib'
```

any suggestions about this?

Comment: Post minimal reproducing example.

Comment: I suggest that try to use different upper version of llvm and clean install. I am mostly encountering this _ZN...something errors because of version incompatibleness.